# pythonanywhere not displaying css right

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles, pythonanywhere

I am having difficulties with python anywhere where my css is not loading or not laoding correctly
any assistance

What it looks like on localhost
[image: What it supposed to look like]

What it looks like On pythonanywhere.
http://bcalitz.pythonanywhere.com/

[[image: What it looks like on python anywhere1]

Static Files:

[image]

***Settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/BCalitz/Blog/static'
```

When I hover over the Testing Blog #1 in the browser using devTools it highlights in the correct size but wont display it?

I think it might have something to do with lists as all my other pages with lists the CSS for it is not working

Comment: Did you run the `collectstatic` management command on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: yes, and I just today got it working seemed like I just had to make a new domain. So I am guessing it  was a bug on their end